# Etymology of the word "smaragd"?

Tags: etymology

I know that this word is used to describe a variation of an emerald, although many dictionaries do not include this word. 
One that does is [Merriam-Webster](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/smaragd):

> Middle English *smaragde,* from Latin *smaragdus,* from Greek *smaragdos,* of Semitic origin; akin to Akkadian *barraqtu* gemstone

What is the etymology of this word **smaragd**? Is the word *emerald* directly related to it? There is a superficial resemblance between the two words.

Comment: The only time I ever heard the word is in my mother tongue, which is Hungarian.
When you directly translate 'emerald' in English to Hungarian, you get the word 'smaragd'.

Comment: What is up with it? What do you mean? Here is a dictionary entry that describes the origin: http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/smaragd

Comment: And what is up with closing the question?  It's a fascinating word that we can trace back to the Greek and understand the relationship to the modern word *emerald* (including the sound change from *gd* to *ld*).  But the CPVPV got there first.

Comment: @deadrat I edited the question and voted to reopen it. But some could still think this question lacks the research.

Comment: @Rathony Thank you.  We happen to disagree on the research requirement, and perhaps one day I'll write a meta-question on my point of view.  My objection is to reflexively closing low-rep user's ill-phrased questions instead of addressing the interesting underlying usage issue.

Comment: @deadrat My pleasure. We had some disagreements on some issues. :-) We can't have the same opinion on all issues. I understand the reason why those five users decided to close the question while I believe this question is interesting. I am trying to be more neutral than before.

Comment: Did you look [at all???](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/smaragd)  *Middle English smaragde, from Latin smaragdus, from Greek smaragdos, of Semitic origin;*  (Why did a question closed for no research get reopened, if Opie still has done no research???)

Comment: @deadrat I've improved the question and await your answer :-)

Comment: @AndrewLeach: the new question you added can be answered by looking up "emerald" in a dictionary: http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/emerald

Comment: Well, readers are very welcome to improve further or vote to close, but the answer appears worthwhile and uses dictionaries which might not readily come to mind.

Comment: I'm confused.  If the question contains the answer, how is it a valid question?

Comment: @AndrewLeach Thank you. As you can see AS-K beat me to it.

Answer (score 2):

The definition posted hints at a semitic origin, which sounds likely - one (relatively archaic) Hebrew word for emerald is *izmargad* (אזמרגד), a close similarity.

However, Hebrew Wikitionary [claims](https://he.wiktionary.org/wiki/%D7%90%D7%96%D7%9E%D7%A8%D7%92%D7%93) that the word has only been in use in Hebrew since the fifth century AD, placing it *after* the Greek usages, and likely to have been influenced by the Greek, rather than influencing it.

The same source claims that the ultimate root for the word resides in Sanskrit *marakata*, or "green", which seems to be corroborated by some [online Sanskrit dictionaries](http://sanskritdictionary.com/?q=marakata) whose veracity I cannot evaluate:

> **marakata**  n. an emerald    [ confer, compare Greek ; Latin *smaragdus*.]

As to how smaragdos* evolved into *emerald*, [Etymonline](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=emerald&allowed_in_frame=0) gives a good overview:

Greek *smaragdos* -> Latin *smaragdus* -> Medieval Latin *esmeraldus* -> Old French *esmeraude* -> French *emeraude* -> English *emerald*.

The same source also claims that the road from Sanskrit *marakata* to Greek *smaragdos* passed through the Semitic root *baraq* (shine), which can be found in the other Hebrew word for emerald, *bareqet*, but I'm not familiar enough with the phonetic shifts between Sanskrit and Semitic languages to say if that's likely.

Comment: Thank you for an excellent answer.  My own contribution is really just an extended comment.  If you feel, the information might be useful in your answer, you may import it, and I will delete mine.

Answer (score 2):

Latin introduces words into English in two ways -- directly and circuitously via Old French.  Thus the Latin word *smaragdus* remains in
Biblical translations from the Vulgate, like Wycliffe's.  In Wycliffe's *Revelation*, the green foundation stone of heaven is *smaragdus*, not *emerald*.  Likewise, in scientific contexts, we have the *Smaragdine Table* (a translation of *Tabula Smaragdina*), a medieval-era book on alchemy.  In mineralogy, *smaragdite* is a bright green silicate mineral.

According to the *OED*, the two forms entered the language at about the same time. *Smaragdus* (as *smaragd*) in 1272; *emerald* (as *emeraundis*) in 1300.  One can only speculate on why the latter became popular and the former became obsolete.